# Planning to avoid API requests exceeded last 24 hours

Tags: api, limits

We are planning to do daily integration runs to salesforce using informatica from an external system. The volume of records are expected to be between 50,000 to 300,000 and this will be done on contacts and a bunch of related custom objects. Here are my questions.

1. Will every insert or update on a custom object will be counted as an api request or if we use a bulk upload with a batch size of 5000 , will this be counted as 1 api request?
2. Is there any documentation on how does salesforce calculate api requests from external applications like informatica data loads, outlook etc?
3. How do we plan such a way so that we can avoid api limits exceeded in 24 hours?

Answer (score 3):

1) The Bulk API has it's own limits [described here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm).

2) Depending on which API has been used, different limits may apply. In this case, the bulk API does not count towards the total API requests in your org.

> These limits do not apply to functional limits of Salesforce APIs that are not tied to API calls. An example would be the Batch Limit for Bulk API, which is governed by its own limit, and not monitored as an API usage limit.
>   [Described here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm#rate_limits_title)

3) If you're exceeding the total number of API requests per 24 hours in your org you should start considering reducing the frequency of external systems sending requests to your org. If it doesn't need to be real-time, make requests less often and in bulk.

Comment: We have exceeded the 24 API call limits with data loads during an integration using Boomi. Not sure how that compares.

Comment: It depends on how the 3rd party tool is integrated and configured. Different APIs, different batch sizes etc etc.